# Changing output resolution when converting EPS file to PNG in Python Imaging Library

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, eps

I wrote a simple implementation of PIL to convert a list of EPS files to PNG.

```
import Image
for infile in sys.argv[1:]:
    f, e = os.path.splitext(infile)
    outfile = f+".png"
    try:
        im = Image.open(infile)
        im.save(outfile, dpi = (1000, 1000))
    except IOError:
        print "Error"
```

Although the dpi flag changes the PNG's file resolution, it doesn't increase the resolution of the im object. This means my output PNG image has very low quality. Is there a way to increase the resolution of the im object? This code doesn't work.

```
im = Image.open(infile, dpi = (1000, 1000))
```

Ideas?

Comment: You would need to change the resolution as part of the `open` process. Unfortunately I don't know how to do that.

Comment: I think you're right. I'll keep digging.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/EpsImagePlugin.py this is implemented by calling ghostscript:

```
# Build ghostscript command
command = ["gs",
           "-q",                    # quite mode
           "-g%dx%d" % size,        # set output geometry (pixels)
           "-dNOPAUSE -dSAFER",     # don't pause between pages, safe mode
           "-sDEVICE=ppmraw",       # ppm driver
           "-sOutputFile=%s" % file,# output file
           "- >/dev/null 2>/dev/null"]
```

the size option only changes the figure size but does not rescale it.
Maybe a bug report to the PIL developers would be useful here.

As workaround, and provided you have the ImageMagick commandline tools installed, you could use this as workaround:

```
import os
cmd = 'convert test.ps test.png'
os.system(cmd)
```

This works fine on my system, without loosing quality.

This version gives a bit more control on the resolution you obtain:

```
import os
cmd = "convert -density 300 test.ps test.png"
os.system(cmd)
```

Comment: Wow great work, thanks a lot for the workaround. I'll see what PIL says about it.

Answer (score 1):

Another work-around is to make the geometry or the text very large in the ps/eps. For my application, I'm rendering latex in EPS and converting to PNG. I simply set the font size to a larger number (200 pt) and the PNG quality is perfect. If you are generating the EPS content, this will work for you.